Effective lower bound on square root
Consider $r \in (0,1)$ and $t_1 <0$ and $t_2 \in \mathbb R.$
I want to show that there exists a constant $C_r>0$ such that
$$t_1 (1 - 2 r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r} \ge C_r (\vert t_1\vert + \vert t_2\vert).$$
Does anyone know about ways to establish this?
I was able to make some partial progress:
One can notice that
$$ \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r} \ge \frac{-t_1 +2 \vert t_2\vert \sqrt{(1 - r) r}}{\sqrt{2}} .$$
This implies that
$$t_1 (1 - 2 r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r} \ge -t_1 ( 2 r+2^{-1/2} -1) +\sqrt{2} \vert t_2\vert \sqrt{(1 - r) r}  .$$
Thus, the result is true as long as $r>1/2-2^{-3/2}$. However, I am unable to show the result for $r \in (0, 1/2-2^{-3/2}]$.

Using $- t_1^2 (1 - 2 r)^2 + t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r = 4r(1-r)(t_1^2 + t_2^2) > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} &= \frac{- t_1^2 (1 - 2 r)^2 + t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r}{-t_1 (1 - 2 r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r}}\\
 &= \frac{4r(1 - r)(t_1^2 + t_2^2)}{-t_1 (1 - 2 r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r}}\\
 &\ge \frac{4r(1 - r)(t_1^2 + t_2^2)}{2 \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r}}\\
 &\ge \frac{4r(1 - r)(t_1^2 + t_2^2)}{2 \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2}}\\
 &= 2r(1-r)\sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2}\\
 &\ge r(1-r)\sqrt{2}\, (|t_1| + |t_2|)
\end{align*}
where we use $4r(1-r) \le 1$.

Could you explain the third line? To alter the denominator, you need to use the inequality $-t_1(1-2r) \leq \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1-r)r}$, I believe. How is this obtained?

@Sambo Because $- t_1^2 (1 - 2 r)^2 + t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2 (1 - r) r = 4r(1-r)(t_1^2 + t_2^2) > 0$. In other words, if $A^2 < B^2$ and $B  > 0$, then $|A| < B$.

I see, that makes sense.

It's a very interesting proof; the observation in your first line was very surprising to me. However, this does make it sensitive to the factor multiplying $t_2^2$ in the square root.

We split into two cases: $r \geq \tfrac{1}{2}$, and $r < \tfrac{1}{2}$. In the first case, we have $1-2r \leq 0$, which means $t_1(1-2r) \geq 0$. Thus, we can just use the classic inequality between the 1-norm and the 2-norm.
\begin{align*}
t_1(1-2r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2(1-r)r}
&\geq \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2(1-r)r}
\\
&\geq |t_1| + |t_2|\sqrt{4(1-r)r}
\end{align*}
In this case, we pick $C_r = \min\left\{1, \sqrt{4(1-r)r}\right\}$.
In the case $r < \tfrac{1}{2}$, we have $0 < (1-2r) < 1$. Therefore, we can pick $s$ such that $0 < (1-2r) < s < 1$. Then we split the square root terms into parts $s$ and $1-s$. Each of these can then be bounded by $t_1$ or $t_2$.
\begin{align*}
t_1(1-2r) + \sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2(1-r)r}
&= t_1(1-2r) + s\sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2(1-r)r} + (1-s)\sqrt{t_1^2 + 4 t_2^2(1-r)r}
\\
&\geq t_1(1-2r) + s\sqrt{t_1^2} + (1-s)\sqrt{4 t_2^2 (1-r)r}
\\
&= -|t_1|(1-2r) + s|t_1| + |t_2|(1-s)\sqrt{4(1-r)r}
\\
&= |t_1|(s-(1-2r)) + |t_2|(1-s)\sqrt{4(1-r)r}
\end{align*}
By the choice of $s$, the constants multiplying $|t_1|$ and $|t_2|$ are positive, and we can pick $C_r = \min\left\{ s-(1-2r), (1-s)\sqrt{4(1-r)r} \right\} > 0$.

@RiverLi I think each case should be ok now.
